# Usar o PDO do PHP para search

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Onde está o erro em meu código. Não sei o motivo do porquê ele não retorna o resultado da pesquisa.

```
<?php
require_once('db_connect.php');
$conectar = new 
PDO("mysql:host=$host;bancodedados=$bancodedados;charset=utf8", 
$usuario, $senha);

$nomeProduto = $_POST['nomeProduto'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM nilo_db.nilo_tb WHERE nomeProduto = 
:nomeProduto";
$queryResult = $conectar->prepare($sql);
$queryExec = $queryResult- 
>execute(array(":nomeProduto"=>$nomeProduto));
if($queryExec){
    if($queryResult->rowCount()>0){
        foreach($queryResult as $row){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="col">
                    <?php echo $row['nomeProduto'] ?>
                    <?php echo $row['codigoProduto'] ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php }
       }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Clique em [edit] e ponha as ultimas linhas do log de erros do PHP que facilita pra gente ajudar. Tem uma quebra de linha no `->` do execute, mas imagino que isso tenha sido ao colar o código aqui né?

Comment: Sim, foi ao colocar o execute aqui, porém, o problema é que ele não retorna erro algum.

Comment: No log de erros sempre aparece (se for erro mesmo, pode simplesmente acontecer de sua query não estar retornando nada), por isso pedi pra acrescentar.

Comment: Tenho reparado que você já fez várias perguntas porém reparei também que você não marcou nenhuma como aceita. É boa pratica marcar uma resposta como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079.

Answer (score 0):

- Na string de conexão mude `bancodedados=$bancodedados` para `dbname=$bancodedados`
- Caso isso não tenha sido ao colar o código aqui, acerte essa linha de código

  ```
  $queryExec = $queryResult- 
  >execute(array(":nomeProduto"=>$nomeProduto));
  ```

  para evitar erros do tipo `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '>' in ....`

  > O correto é sem quebra de linha `->` e sem espaços

  `$queryExec = $queryResult->execute(array(":nomeProduto"=>$nomeProduto));`

**Código corrigido**

```
    $conectar = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$bancodedados;charset=utf8", $usuario, $senha);

    $nomeProduto = $_POST['nomeProduto'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nilo_db.nilo_tb WHERE nomeProduto = :nomeProduto";

    $queryResult = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $queryExec = $queryResult->execute(array(":nomeProduto"=>$nomeProduto));
    if($queryExec){
        if($queryResult->rowCount()>0){
            foreach($queryResult as $row){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col">
                        <?php echo $row['nomeProduto'] ?>
                        <?php echo $row['codigoProduto'] ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php }
           }
        }
```

**Como conectar um banco de dados MySQL utilizando PHP**

> Utilizando PDO

```
$conectar = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST;dbname=NOME_DB", "USUARIO", "SENHA");
```

- HOST: Host de conexão com o banco de dados;
- USUARIO: Usuário de acesso ao banco de dados da conexão;
- SENHA: Senha de acesso ao banco de dados especificado na conexão;
- NOME_DB: Nome da base a qual você deseja fazer acesso.